# HTML fieldset with no fields

Tags: html

I'm writing a blog article, and I want to add a "Note" box, which I want to look pretty much exactly like a `<fieldset>` with a `<legend>`

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Note</legend>
    Please take note of this.
</fieldset>
```

(see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)

As you can see, this `<fieldset>` won't actually contain any fields, so it seems a bit of a dirty hack just to make the layout work easily.

Does anyone know if there's another tag similar to `<fieldset>` \ `<legend>` that is more applicable to the text content that it will be containing?

I can do it with CSS but I just wonder if there's a HTML element that will make the markup nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a semantic perspective, tag choices should not be dictated by desired presentation (what you want it to *look like*), but rather to describe what the content actually *is*. On the other hand, there's nothing that behaves quite like `legend` (it is a rather odd element), so there really is no solid alternative, but you can come close. [here's one example](http://jsfiddle.net/AEec5/) out of the many possible solutions:

```
<div>
    <h3>Notes</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text...</p>
</div>
```

```
div {
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
h3 {
    margin-top:-30px; /* estimated, you can be more accurate */
    background:#fff;  /* hide the top border behind it */
    float:left;       /* make it the smallest width possible */
}
```

I don't believe it's *technically* illegal to have a fieldset with no form inputs (meaning, your markup will still validate), but it's really meant to be used for forms. If you can find an alternative solution via CSS, it would be the ideal way to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Cheers, I was just curious if I was missing something, I guess I wasn't! CSS it is, I just wondered if there was a specific semantic tag for what I was trying to do since it seems like it it something that would be common.

Comment: `<legend>` has very unique behavior that is difficult (if not impossible) to emulate perfectly with CSS. The basis of your question is actually rather common.